# JIRA 6.0 Time-Spent calculation

Tags: jira

JIRA's time spent calculation seems to be adding quite a few hours to actual time spent.

If I add up the columns I get a much different result than when JIRA adds up the columns.

My question: How does JIRA arrive at this amount of time tpent in the default time tracking report?

[image: Jira is a filthy liar]

*Edit*: Maybe a JIRA "day" is 8 hours? That seems silly to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that by default 1d is not a real day, but it's a Jira day, which is 8 hours apparently.

Answer (score -1):

1 day is one working day, of course. This is an issue tracking and project planning system what else could "a day"?
  Also this is configurable in JIRA...

Comment: This is a setting in JIRA.